# Applying transformation to new data Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I am using Spark (core/mlib) with Java, version 2.3.1.

I am applying three transformations to a Dataset - StringIndexer, OneHotEncoderEstimator, VectorAssember - this is to a transform a categorical variable in my dataset into individual columns of 1 and 0 for each category. On my train data, this transformation works with no issues, everything is as expected, and I am saving this model to file.

My issue comes when I try to use this model on a new datapoint:

```
public static double loadModel(Obj newData) {
    SparkSession spark = Shots.buildSession();

    //Function which applies transformations
    Dataset<Row> data = buildDataset(spark, Arrays.asList(newData));

    LogisticRegressionModel lrModel = LogisticRegressionModel.load(modelPath);
    //Error is thrown here as the model doesn't seem to understand the input
    Dataset<Row> preds = lrModel.transform(data);
    preds.show();
}
```

The issue, I believe, is that the transformation is now being applied to only one row of data which outputs only one category for the categorical feature and a vector with only one element after transformation. This causes an error when the LogisticRegressionModel transform is applied, which is expecting a vector with length greater than one for that feature... I think.

I know my error is not knowing how to apply the train transform to the new data... but I am unsure where exactly the error is and, as a result, do not know where to find the answer (is the issue with saving the model, do I need to save something else like the pipeline, etc.).

The actual error being thrown is -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: BLAS.dot(x: Vector, y:Vector) was given Vectors with non-matching sizes: x.size = 7, y.size = 2 - the reason why I have come to the conclusions above is a visual examination of the data.
```

An example may help explain: I have a categorical feature with 3 values [Yes, No, Maybe]. My train data includes all three values, I end up with a vector feature of length 3 signifying the category.

I am then using the same pipeline on a single data point to predict a value but the categorical feature can only be Yes, No, or Maybe as there is only one data point. Therefore, when you apply the same transformation as above you ended up with a vector with one element, as opposed to three, causing the model transform to throw an error.

Comment: Please post the complete stack-trace?

Answer (score 0):

In general you don't use API correctly. Correct workflow should include preserving a whole set of `Models` (in your case it will be at least `StringIndexerModel`, other components looks like `Transformers`) trained in the process and reapplying these on the new data.

The most convenient way of doing it is using `Pipeline`:

```
 val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Arrray(indexer, encoder, assembler, lr))
 val pipelineModel = pipeline.fit(data)

 pipelineModel.transform(data)
```

`PipelineModels` can be save as any other component, as long as all its stages are writable.

Comment: I may have misunderstood you but you appear to be answering a question that wasn't asked. My problem is not building the model but applying the model to new data. The models works fine and the pipeline is being reapplied (as the comment in my code indicates). The issue is that the output of the pipeline is causing an error when applied to the saved model.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was that I was saving the model at the wrong point.

To preserve the effect of previous transformations you need to fit the pipeline to the data **and then** write/save the model. This means saving PipelineModel rather than Pipeline. If you fit after you load the data, then the transformation will be reapplied in full and you will lose the state required for the transformation to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same issue. StringIndexer will fail for new values in test or new data so we can choose to skip those unknown values.

```
new StringIndexer().setHandleInvalid("skip")
```

or pass union of both the train and test data to the pipeline and split it post-transformation.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. `handle_data_PipelineModel ==> df ---> split_dataset ==> train_df/test_df--> arithmetic_PipelineModel----->test_model--->evaluate`
2. `df == > split_dataset ==> train_df/test_df--> PipelineModel(handle_data_stage and arithmetic_stage) ---> probably error`

Option 1 is safe: You need to save `handle_data_PipelineModel` and `arithmetic_PipelineModel`.

Option 2 is bad: No matter how you save the model. When you split data first, the distribution of `train_df` and `test_df` will change。

Note: The divided data set must not be processing data prior to the PipelineModel.

Comment: Hi and welcome. I have tried to fix your answer, I hope that I haven't changed its meaning.